# PHP require doesn't work for sub directory

Tags: php

I am working on Yii2/CentOS8/Nginx:.

`require (__DIR__ . '/../test.php');` work

`require (__DIR__ . '/../config/test.php');` doesn't work

test.php and config/test.php exist.
why does it happen?
Anybody help me please

Comment: sanity check.. does `DIR . '/../config/test.php'`? exist, its not a lot to go on fancy providing us with error message?

Comment: You need to show us your file/folder structure. Specifically for where the file with these require's is in relation to the files you're trying to require, or we won't know if the paths are correct or not.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. One thing you can add to improve the question in the future is the error you were getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just fixed. that was cause of selinux permission.

```
chcon -Rt httpd_sys_content_t /path/to/www
```